# how to append mega menu to sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, menu

i want to add this extension  on sidebarand my code is such this

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">

{{widget type="megamenupro/megamenupro" menu="4"}}
```

[Link](http://www.emthemes.com/commercial-magento-extensions/em-mega-menu.html)
But does not display on slider.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento SE, feel free to check out this post on how to ask a question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . Unfortunately, questions about 3rd party modules are off topic on Magento StackExchange so I suggest you contact the developers of the Megamenupro module to help you fix your problem